# jquery mobile android t9 disable

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, android, mobile

Is there a way to disable T9 on a certain input?
I made auto complete, but T9 is really annoying.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

T9 is a phone feature instead of browser feature so no.

Comment: ok.. but is there a way to disable it to full application in android?